# variance of a mixture in terms of the mean and variance of each component

Tags: matlab, mixture-distribution, bimodal

I am following the MATLAB example to fit a mixture of two normal distribution that you can find [here](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/stats/examples/fitting-custom-univariate-distributions.html#zmw57dd0e597)

At some point it is defined the inital guess for the standard deviation as:

```
sigmaStart = sqrt(var(x) - .25*diff(muStart).^2)
```

where x are the data and muStart is the initial guess for the mean (i.e. centered at the two quartiles of the data)

using my data sigma is a non real number since I have

```
var(x) = 0.1045
muStart = [0.7000    1.3600];
```

Could you please tell me what's wrong? Peraphs the formula to calculate the sigmaStart?

Comment: Could you show a sample that has the lower quartile at 0.7 and the upper quartile at 1.36 and yet has the variance at 0.1045?

Comment: @Glen_b my data.... https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OEUZHGRRZoLkRtriNhPjsLoq383c6DC5mhuLzr6G1Ic/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @Glen_b The SD is $\sqrt{0.1045}=0.3233$.

Comment: @whuber I don't understand why you marked it as duplicate...I am following the Matlab example... I assume that they know how to compute the sigma of a mixture.. I am trying to understand what went wrong in following this example

Comment: Are you asking us to debug your code?  Could you clarify where you want help?  (I do see that the formula for initial values suggested in your reference is a particularly poor one: in *the majority* of cases it will fail.)

Comment: @whuber it is not my code. I am following an example from the Matab webpage.. following this example with the data I attached I get a non real sigmaStart... so that I cannot fit the pdf of my data. The example is to fit a mixture of normal distributions, I have a mixture of normal distributions...where is the error?

Comment: OK, it is clear your question is not a duplicate.  If you can, though, please edit it to include the clarifying information in your comments.